# Issue with Threading

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to be able to use threads to run two loops at once within my program for a sort of game like program. However I'm not entirely sure how to use Threads and I am encountering errors I know nothing about. I will post code but ignore most of it, it's a somewhat hollow shell of what I want it to be I just need to get threads working to start cleaning it all up.
I'm getting the error "is not abstract and does not override" and it is highlighting the "class game implements runnable" section. This is the code:

```
public class game implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run(int time){
        try{
            time = 1;
            while (time<=10){
                Thread.sleep(10);
                System.out.print(time);
                time++;            
            }
            char clearer = (char)(12);
            System.out.print(clearer);
            System.out.println("You have ran out of time! Game over!");
            System.exit(0);
        }catch (Exception e){}
    }

    public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("Welcome to pseudo-Where's Wally, look for the lower cal l character.");
        Thread.sleep(500);
        System.out.println("You get 10 seconds to find it.");
        Thread.sleep(500);
        System.out.println("Ready?..");
        char clear = (char)(12);
        Thread.sleep(500);
        System.out.print(clear);
        boolean timer = false, col = false, guess = false;
        int length = 5, time = 0, rowNum = 1, y = 0;        
        String manip = ("");
        int x = (length*length);
        Random gen = new Random();
        int find = gen.nextInt(x)+1;
        for (int collumn = 0; collumn<=length; collumn++){
            for (int row = 0; row<=length; row++){
                while (!col){
                    y++;
                    System.out.print("  "+y);                    
                    if (y-1 == length){
                        System.out.println();
                        System.out.println();
                        col = true;
                    } 
                }
                System.out.print("  I");   
                manip = manip + ("  I");  
            }
            System.out.println("\t" + rowNum);
            rowNum++;            
            manip = manip + ("  I");            
        }

        boolean contin = false;
        do{
            if (find%3==0){
                contin = true;
                find = find - 1;
            } else if (find%3>0){
                find = find - 1;
            }
        }while (!contin);

        String newManip = manip.substring(0,find)+'l'+manip.substring(find+1);
        String subOne = newManip.substring(0,18);
        String subTwo = newManip.substring(18,36);
        String subThree = newManip.substring(36,54);
        String subFour = newManip.substring(54,72);
        String subFive = newManip.substring(72,90);
        String subSix = newManip.substring(90,108);
        System.out.println(subOne);
        System.out.println(subTwo);
        System.out.println(subThree);
        System.out.println(subFour);
        System.out.println(subFive);
        System.out.println(subSix);

        Thread threadA = new ThreadA();        

        threadA.start();

        while(guess != true){
            System.out.print("Answer (Only one try): ");
            int answer = sc.nextInt();
            if (answer == finalAnswer){
                guess = true;                
            }     
        }
    }
}
```

Cheers for any help.

Comment: Your error has nothing at all to do with threading.

Comment: You don't override `run()` method by the way, so you're not really implementing `Runnable`.

Comment: Could you help then, if you know what the error is?

Comment: Write a new program that does nothing but make 2 threads where each prints something in a loop and then build from there.

Answer (score 1):

In order to implement `Runnable` you need to override the `run()` method (unless your class is `abstract`, which opens another discussion). What you have in your `game` class is `run(int time)`, which won't count.

From the [Runnable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) API:

> The Runnable interface should be implemented by any class whose instances are intended to be executed by a thread. **The class must define a method of no arguments called run**.

Bold added by me.